# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on') in React

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, webrtc, typeerror

I'm getting this error "cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')
at Home.jsx:17:1"
Here is the HomePage(in client) code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import {useSocket} from "../providers/socket";

const Homepage = () => {
    const { socket } = useSocket();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    
    const [email, setEmail] = useState();
    const [roomId, setRoomId] = useState();

    const handleRoomJoined = useCallback(({roomId}) => {
        navigate(`/room/${roomId}`);
    }, [navigate]);

    useEffect(() => {
        socket.on('joined-room', handleRoomJoined);
        return () =>{
            socket.off('joined-room', handleRoomJoined);
        }
    }, [handleRoomJoined, socket])

    const handleJoinRoom = () => {
        socket.emit("join-room", {emailId: email, roomId});
    };

    return (
        <div className="homepage-containter">
            <div className="input-container">
                <input value = {email} onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} type="email" placeholder="Enter your email here" />
                <input value = {roomId} onChange={e => setRoomId(e.target.value)} type="text" placeholder="Enter your room code" />
                <button onClick={handleJoinRoom} type='submit'>Enter Room</button> 
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Homepage
```

code for **socket.jsx** is as following:

```
import React, {  useMemo } from "react";
import {io} from 'socket.io-client';

const SocketContext = React.createContext(null);

export const useSocket = () =>{
    return React.useContext(SocketContext);
};

export const SocketProvider = (props) => {
    const socket = useMemo(() => io("http://localhost:8001"), [])

    return (
        <SocketContext.Provider value={socket}>
            {props.children}
        </SocketContext.Provider>
    )
};
```

I'm trying to assign the room when user enter emailId and roomId.

Comment: It means the error says like "there is no attribute `on` of socket hook" that what you are using it. Could you please post the socket code to your question?

Comment: I have added the socket code, can you please check why I'm getting this error.

Comment: You can check my answer and can do edits to your files.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [socket docs](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-api/), which is a third-party library, You don't have to use `SocketProvider` and `useMemo` in your socket.jsx. And while creating Hooks no need to create any context just for using a third-party library.

You could do like these in `socket.jsx`:

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

export const useSocket = () => {
     const socket = io("http://localhost:8001");
     return socket;
};
```

And do some changes in `HomePage.jsx`:

```
const socket = useSocket(); // remove curly braces from the socket
//...
const [email, setEmail] = useState(""); //set it as empty string not `null or undefined` it gives uncontrolled change input error 
const [roomId, setRoomId] = useState("");

//...
```

PS: for [uncontrolled changing in an input](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/input#im-getting-an-error-a-component-is-changing-an-uncontrolled-input-to-be-controlled) error you shouldn't set `useState` as `null and undefined`. It should be always an empty string `""`.

I hope this helps you.